# Selenium automation on Oracle applications

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, oracleapplications

Is there a way we can perform selenium automation(with Java) on Oracle applications?  On the Oracle website they have given ways by which we can convert the Oracle applications into Oracle ADF faces applications and then automate it with selenium or the Oracle application can be converted into a webpage and then it can be automated.

But instead of these two methods is there any other way anyone has tried?  I don't want to use other testing tools like QTP, Oracle ATS or Windows (which is an open source tool). So inspite of all this, is there still a way through which selenium automation can be done on Oracle applications?

Comment: ok, i found one way, if the front end of the oracle applications is a webpage then selenium can be used. if the front end is oracle forms then it cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle applications (I mean EBS/forms) applications, Selenium can't be used.As it is built Oracle forms, which is on Java applet technology.

Oracle ATS is the best tool to test such applications, it provides both functional and load testing support for EBS/forms applications.

BTW: all oracle EBS/forms QA use this tool for inside Oracle for testing EBS/forms applicatons.

ref: 1. official page:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/index.html

ref 2. how whole Oracle inside EBS QA group use our tool for testing EBS.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCvn4S3hGdM

above video presented by Prasanti Madireddi ,Senior Director, EBS Quality Assurance.  Who owns the EBS product  testing inside oracle.

I am a dev manager for Oracle ATS tool, we worked a lot with Oracle EBS group and this is why our product is so good to testing EBS application.

For Oracle Fusion applications, which is using build using ADF technology, as it is pure web, selenium is able to test it, but very inconvenient.

Oracle ATS tool has powerful feature to fully support recording and playback for testing all Fusion applications.

And for Fusion, also the whole test engineer for Fusion applications are all using Oracle ATS tool for testing. There are hundreds of QA engineer works on Fusion product, such as CRM, HCM, Financial, SCM, etc...

Hundreds of thousands test script are written using Oracle ATS, and run every day....